# Select query taking lot of time to execute

Tags: oracle11g, sql-tuning

I have this query in my application

```
SELECT
           /*+ parallel (4) */
           a.orgkey     AS cifid,
           a.strfield19 AS old_cif_id,
           a.cust_first_name,
           a.cust_middle_name,
           a.cust_last_name,
           a.primary_sol_id AS sol_id,
           (
                  SELECT lang.localetext
                  FROM   crmuser.categories cat,
                         crmuser.category_lang lang
                  WHERE  cat.categoryid=lang.categoryid
                  AND    cat.categorytype= 'PERSONSALUTATION'
                  AND    cat.bank_id =
                         (
                                SELECT bank_id
                                FROM   migadm.migr_det)
                  AND    lang.bank_id =
                         (
                                SELECT bank_id
                                FROM   migadm.migr_det)
                  AND    cat.value= a.salutation) AS saluatation,
           a.segmentation_class                   AS segmentation_class,
           CASE
                      WHEN corp_id IS NULL THEN
                                 (
                                        SELECT lang.localetext
                                        FROM   crmuser.categories cat,
                                               crmuser.category_lang lang
                                        WHERE  cat.categoryid=lang.categoryid
                                        AND    cat.categorytype= 'SEGMENTATION_CLASS'
                                        AND    cat.bank_id =
                                               (
                                                      SELECT bank_id
                                                      FROM   migadm.migr_det)
                                        AND    lang.bank_id =
                                               (
                                                      SELECT bank_id
                                                      FROM   migadm.migr_det)
                                        AND    cat.value= a.segmentation_class)
                      ELSE
                            (
                            SELECT lang.localetext
                            FROM   crmuser.categories cat,
                                   crmuser.category_lang lang
                            WHERE  cat.categoryid=lang.categoryid
                            AND    cat.categorytype= 'CORP_SEGMENTATION_CLASS'
                            AND    cat.bank_id =
                                   (
                                          SELECT bank_id
                                          FROM   migadm.migr_det)
                            AND    lang.bank_id =
                                   (
                                          SELECT bank_id
                                          FROM   migadm.migr_det)
                            AND    cat.value= a.segmentation_class)
           END          AS segmentation_desc,
           a.subsegment AS subsegment,
           CASE
                      WHEN corp_id IS NULL THEN
                                 (
                                        SELECT lang.localetext
                                        FROM   crmuser.categories cat,
                                               crmuser.category_lang lang
                                        WHERE  cat.categoryid=lang.categoryid
                                        AND    cat.categorytype= 'SUB_SEGMENT'
                                        AND    cat.bank_id =
                                               (
                                                      SELECT bank_id
                                                      FROM   migadm.migr_det)
                                        AND    lang.bank_id =
                                               (
                                                      SELECT bank_id
                                                      FROM   migadm.migr_det)
                                        AND    cat.value= a.subsegment)
                      ELSE
                            (
                            SELECT lang.localetext
                            FROM   crmuser.categories cat,
                                   crmuser.category_lang lang
                            WHERE  cat.categoryid=lang.categoryid
                            AND    cat.categorytype= 'CORP_SUB_SEGMENT'
                            AND    cat.bank_id =
                                   (
                                          SELECT bank_id
                                          FROM   migadm.migr_det)
                            AND    lang.bank_id =
                                   (
                                          SELECT bank_id
                                          FROM   migadm.migr_det)
                            AND    cat.value= a.subsegment)
           END AS subsegment_desc,
           CASE
                      WHEN a.corp_id IS NULL THEN a.strfield10
                      ELSE c.struserfield4
           END AS reserve_bank_code,
           CASE
                      WHEN a.corp_id IS NULL THEN a.strfield11
                      ELSE c.struserfield5
           END         AS form50_code,
           a.sector    AS pri_sic_code,
           a.subsector AS sec_sic_code,
           CASE
                      WHEN a.corp_id IS NULL THEN a.struserfield3
                      ELSE c.struserfield3
           END                  AS kyc_indicator,
           a.defaultaddresstype AS defaultaddresstype,
           b.address_line1,
           b.address_line2,
           b.address_line3,
           CASE
                      WHEN a.corp_id IS NULL THEN
                                 (
                                        SELECT (ad.address_line1
                                                      ||' '
                                                      ||ad.address_line2
                                                      ||' '
                                                      ||ad.address_line3)
                                        FROM   crmuser.address ad
                                        WHERE  a.orgkey=ad.orgkey
                                        AND    ad. preferredaddress='Y'
                                        AND
                                               (
                                                      SELECT migration_date
                                                      FROM   migadm.migr_det) BETWEEN ad.start_date AND    ad.end_date)
                      ELSE
                            (
                            SELECT (ad.address_line1
                                          ||' '
                                          ||ad.address_line2
                                          ||' '
                                          ||ad.address_line3)
                            FROM   crmuser.address ad
                            WHERE  a.orgkey=ad.orgkey
                            AND    ad.preferredaddress='Y' and
                                   (
                                          SELECT migration_date
                                          FROM   migadm.migr_det) BETWEEN ad.start_date AND    ad.end_date)
           END        AS postal_adress,
           b.zip      AS postal_code,
           a.gender   AS gender,
           a.cust_dob AS date_of_birth,
           (
                  SELECT p.email
                  FROM   crmuser.phoneemail p
                  WHERE  p.orgkey = a.orgkey
                  AND    p.preferredflag='Y'
                  AND    phoneoremail='EMAIL'
                  AND    ROWNUM =1) email_id,
           (
                  SELECT p.phonenocountrycode
                  FROM   crmuser.phoneemail p
                  WHERE  p.orgkey = a.orgkey
                  AND    p.preferredflag='Y'
                  AND    phoneoremail='PHONE'
                  AND    ROWNUM =1) AS phone_cntry_code,
           (
                  SELECT p.phonenocitycode
                  FROM   crmuser.phoneemail p
                  WHERE  p.orgkey = a.orgkey
                  AND    p.preferredflag='Y'
                  AND    phoneoremail='PHONE'
                  AND    ROWNUM =1) AS phone_city_code,
           (
                  SELECT '+'
                                || p.phonenocountrycode
                                || '('
                                || p.phonenocitycode
                                || ')'
                                || p.phonenolocalcode
                  FROM   crmuser.phoneemail p
                  WHERE  p.orgkey = a.orgkey
                  AND    p.preferredflag = 'Y'
                  AND    phoneoremail='PHONE') phone_no,
           --CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM crmuser.miscellaneousinfo m WHERE a.orgkey=m.orgkey and type = 'CURRENCY') = 1 THEN (SELECT strtext10 FROM crmuser.miscellaneousinfo m WHERE a.orgkey=m.orgkey and type = 'CURRENCY')
           -- WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM crmuser.corpmiscellaneousinfo m WHERE a.orgkey=m.orgkey and type = 'CURRENCY') = 1 THEN (SELECT str1 FROM crmuser.corpmiscellaneousinfo m WHERE a.orgkey=m.orgkey and type = 'CURRENCY')
           --    ELSE
           migadm.getcurrencies(a.orgkey)
           --END
           AS crncy_code,
           CASE
                      WHEN a.corp_id IS NULL THEN a.struserfield15
                      ELSE c.struserfield6
           END                    AS wht_indicator,
           a.cust_swift_code_desc AS cust_swift_code_desc,
           customernreflg         AS customernreflg,
           (
                  SELECT employerid
                  FROM   crmuser.miscellaneousinfo s
                  WHERE  s.orgkey = a.orgkey
                  AND    TYPE ='CURRENT_EMPLOYMENT') AS group_number,
           (
                  SELECT strtext4
                  FROM   crmuser.miscellaneousinfo s
                  WHERE  s.orgkey = a.orgkey
                  AND    TYPE ='CURRENT_EMPLOYMENT' ) AS employment_details,
           --(select EMPLOYERSNAME from crmuser.DEMOGRAPHIC s where s.orgkey = a.orgkey ) AS employment_details,
           (
                  SELECT employeeid
                  FROM   crmuser.miscellaneousinfo s
                  WHERE  s.orgkey = a.orgkey
                  AND    TYPE ='CURRENT_EMPLOYMENT' ) AS employeeid,
           --(select EMPLOYERID from crmuser.MISCELLANEOUSINFO s where s.orgkey = a.orgkey ) AS employerid,
           a.manager AS manager,
           CASE
                      WHEN a.corp_id IS NULL THEN d.annual_salary_income
                      ELSE c.average_annualincome
           END AS annual_income,
           c.registration_number
FROM       crmuser.corporate c
right join crmuser.address b
ON         b.orgkey=c.corp_key
right join crmuser.accounts a
ON         b.orgkey=a.orgkey
left join  crmuser.demographic d
ON         a.orgkey=d.orgkey
WHERE      a.bank_id =
           (
                  SELECT bank_id
                  FROM   migadm.migr_det)
AND        a.entity_cre_flag = 'Y'
AND        b.preferredaddress = 'Y'
```

It takes more than 20 minutes to give results. Can someone please help me in tuning this query. I don't have any idea about sql.
I can give the explain plan needed but I don't know how to copy here the 111 rows from plan table

Comment: Even with the plan, we don't know anything about your tabes, indexes, data or volumes. You should start by learning [how to interpret the plan](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/ex_plan.htm). That isn't something an answer here can teach you. But why are you using subqueries instead of (more) joins?

Comment: In addition to what Alex has said, you have very similar subqueries repeated throughout your statement. My first action would be to see if I could combine similar subqueries into a single subquery and then join that to the main table(s). Also, `migadm.migr_det` appears to be a single-row table, so rather than querying it all over the place, you could simply cross join it to the main table(s) and then reference it directly within the query. Also, for the `postal_adress` column (spelling?) you have the same query repeated in your case statement; so remove the case statement?

Comment: If you don't have **any idea** about sql, why are **you** in charge of tuning this query? This makes no sense.

Comment: @mathguy because that is how IT industry works here.